# Alfresco activiti work flow using spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, alfresco, activiti

I want to implement Fellowship concept using alfresco activiti work flow and spring MVC.

Concept of Fellowship work flow

step 1 : Student will submit the fellowship application.

step 2 : fellowship application is approve/reject by the supervisor1 and supervisor2

step 3 : if both supervisor1 and supervisor2 have approved then the form will go to admin

For this above flow I created two tables

```
acad_fellowship_application table contain 

          fellowship_id, //unique Id
          student_id, //student Id
          Amount, //Amount for fellowship


acad_fellowship_application_tran table contain

            fellowship_id
            user_id
            tran_type_id -- supervisor1/supervisor2
            status_id -- Approved/Reject
```

Right Now using spring application I did this like below.

1) After submit the fellowship form one record inserted in acad_fellowship_application table

2) Two records are inserted in acad_fellowship_application_tran table one for supervisor1 and other for supervisor2

3) Supervisor have an option of change status. If both supervisors approve then admin will get the application

I want to implement same thing using alfresco activiti work flow using spring MVC. I have following doubts.

1) How to do this task using alfresco activiti work flow?

2) How to define the process? Is this requirement contain single process or multiple process? When to start the processes?

3) I want to use my own tables to save the details? How and when to save details in my own table? Is there any need to use activiti tables or data in activiti tables to achieve this?

4) Is it possible without using spring boot and rest api's?

Please see the application flow and help me how to do this?
[image]

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No need for spring. Only activiti will be enough.
Create a workflow as shown (replace all service task by user tasks). For review tasks of supervisors keep, keep 2 outcomes Approve and reject. On the exclusive gateway you can put a condition that if both Supervisor's outcomes are approved then only go for admin approval else mail student.

- hope it helped